# Build a Plugin for Java EE

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a eclipse plugin and the example I found was for Java-SE-1.8 so the line in the xml file for the java version was:

```
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

I tried to change the version to this (trying my luck):

```
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaEE-7.0
```

I haven't found anything about which keyword to put there so the plugin will deploy on the Java EE view, can someone help me find what i need to put in there?

Comment: Eclipse plugins are for OSGi Eclipse not Java EE

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the String describing the Execution Environments.

There are two ways to change it:

**Method 1**: In plugin.xml, look in execution environments, click "Add..", then you can choose among the available ones.

[image]

**Method 2**: From menu, open ** Window > Preferences" then expand "Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments**. There you can see the list of environments

[image]

Hope this helps.